# Can not start the Apache tomcat server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, port-number

After changing the port number of tomcat apache to start the server I got the following error. 
Error: could not create the Java Virtual Machine a fatal exception has occurred program will exit.
So server is not starting.Please help

Comment: Do you have a more complete error message?

Comment: most likely incompatibilities between tomcat arch and java arch. Which architecture to you have installed respectively? E.g. Both 32-bit? dont mix it up. also make sure the correct arch is in your path.

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace from catalina.out. You might changed the port to one which is already in use.

Comment: Hi Thilo,Along with the above mentioned error, I am getting this as well. Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start.